# TCPDUMP - Capturing Android HTTPS Data

Tags: android, ssl, https, capture, tcpdump

I need to capture all my HTTP + HTTPS URLs that my android device is requesting.
I already worked with tcpdump and it worked great to capture HTTP requests when listening to port 80 and port 443. My tcpdump command:
tcpdump -vv -s 0 -w /sdcard/output.cap port 80 or port 443

The problem is that I must also capture HTTPS.
Tcpdump is recognizing the request, but obviously (Cause of SSL encryption), I can't read the URL. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the HTTPS server's private key?

Answer (score 2):

Install [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) on a laptop, connect it to the Internet by ethernet, turn that same laptop in a Wi-Fi hotspot. Launch the proxy. Connect to the hotspot with your android device, install the mitm root cert by browsing [mitm.it](http://mitm.it). Once done, you should see the HTTPS traffic in the proxy's console.

Comment: THX, but I can also do that with Fiddler. I actually need it with tcpdump or ssldump.